# Cant Use Facebook API on AppEngine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, oauth

So, I have this grade project where I have to do a mashup and deploy it on AppEngine. So, everything is fine, and I even got it working some months ago, but when I deployed the project again after doing some changes and updating the facebook api, it no longer works.

Thing is, it does works on localhost. The error only occurs when deployed. It's only a normal publish post POST.

So, here's the error:

The URL was blocked: Redirection has failed because the URI is not incluided in the list of OAuth authorised of the application client. Check that the OAuth access of both client and web are active and add all the domains of your apps as OAuth redirection URI

This was translated from spanish so it might not be totally accurate.

So, it seems easy, but I don't really know if the proble is that I have to do something in the configuration of appengine control panel (most likely), in the configuration of the facebook api control panel or if it's something in the project code. I've checked everywhere and have the faint memory of solving this several months ago, but I can't anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Facebook login, you need to tell Facebook the URI of the page that the login will start from.  If you change the URI, then the login process will break.  You can set the URI from this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1234567890/fb-login/

Except that you need your app id in there instead of 1234567890.  You can get there from here:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: It worked perfectly! In fact localhost/uri was added so I indeed did it, but it was so much time ago that I didn't remember how to get around this time. Thanks a lot!